# Java Android Eclipse - Resize/Scale image from directory storage

Tags: java, android, image, resize, scale

I have String like this

```
String path = "storage/sdcard0/Pictures/location/img.jpg";
```

that string is location for file img.jpg. How can i scale/resize that image.
thanks..

Comment: at least you have to try something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 * Resizing image size
 */
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
    try {

        File f = new File(filePath);

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale *= 2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

   Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageHeight);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
   imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: still not working, i was try your code like this.

String path = "storage/sdcard0/Pictures/location/img.jpg";

decodeFile(path, 400, 200); 

but file is still same..

Comment: Under which layout you are putting this image view?
Can you share your complete code. Problem can be somewhere else as well.
This code is working fine for me under a grid layout.

Comment: @EkoPrasetyo let us know if your problem is resolved, else share your code. Don't forget to upvote my answer :)